# Difference between git bundle and .patch

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm working on a project with a git repository, and I want to export the last changes I have done and send it by e-mail.

I need to know the difference between making a *git bundle* and making a *.patch* file, and what is better?

I'm using Tortoise Git, and it give me the option to create the *.patch* file, and it does not give me the option of creating the *git bundle*, this means that the *.patch* file is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [incremental bundle](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) would depend on and be applied to another bundle previously created.

> To bootstrap the process, you can first create a bundle that does not have any basis.
>   You can use a tag to remember up to what commit you last processed, in order to make it easy to later update the other repository with an incremental bundle:

But a patch can be applied on any repo.
In your case, a patch is the right choice (similar to the command [`git format-patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch)).
You don't need to depend on previous patches, for your patch to be applied on a remote repo.

Comment: I didn't write in the question, but I'm supposing both repo are the same repository. I want update both repos.

Comment: Now I see, the patch can be applied to any repo, doesn't care if both have not the same root...

Comment: @RaulOtaño exactly: a patch is just a collection of diff, applied in a certain order. A bundle is a repo in itself, you and only can apply an incremental bundle on top of an existing bundle.

Comment: I made a little test, and tried both, patch and bundle, and I had noticed that the patch create a commit that doesn't match with the original commit (the commit's comment is the same, but the id not), and then, and if I update both projects then int the updated project are two commits, both with the same comment. With the bunlde that doesn't happens.