# How to set up Peer-to-Peer collaboration with Git?

Tags: git, p2p

Because for technical and legal reason the usage of a central repository is for some projects not possible, I would like to set up the versioning with Git in a peer to peer fashion without a catalyzing server. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4):

`git daemon` might be what you are looking for.

Beware that this mechanism exposes your project to the network as it does not have authentication mechanism.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon

Answer (score 3):

This would mean sending patches, through for instance email.

See "[Git Tip of the Week: Patches by Email](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html)"

> One way of getting changes is by providing a patch, or a set of changes which can be applied to a remote repository at the other end.
>
> Git started life as a distributed version control system for the Linux project, which actively uses mail lists both as a discussion mechanism and also as a distribution mechanism for patches (changes) for an existing codebase. (New features are just a special case of patching nothing to add the new code.)

Another option is to [email a `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309), which can be incremental.
It is one file, and you can fetch from it.

It is [different from a patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407577/6309).

Answer (score 2):

When Git used in pure DVCS-mode, it's the same (technically) thing, as using in pseudo CVCS-mode

1. Each side have *any* possible publishing method, which it can provide (ssh://, git://, http://) in order to be reachable from remote
2. `git clone` and|or `git remote add` establish relations between nodes (1:many)
3. `git pull` | `git push` will transfer changesets between nodes

Comment: what publishing method do you think makes most sense for a number of laptops over WLAN?

Comment: @Raffael - *any implementable* (ssh is hard in Windows, http require http-server)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, to open peer-to-peer repo, you could use sharing folder. After activate the folder sharing,

run this command on client side

```
git clone {\\COMPUTER_NAME\DIRECTORY\REPOSITORY}
```

when add file or commit changes from remote node, it should work. The thing to be aware is when push to server node. The server node need to switch to other branch before push by other node,

The server command

```
git branch {NEW_BRANCH_NAME}
git switch {OTHER_BRANCH}
```

and then client command

```
git push {CLONED_REPO_DIR}
```

It limited to only windows user.
Happy sharing