# How do I connect a COPY (an archive, not a clone) of a git repository to its remote?

Tags: git, github, archive

I'd like to know to connect and sync a COPY (an archive, not a clone) of a git repo with its remote repo.

Background:
I have a local and remote repository. I zip up my local repository using git archive and then copy it to a server:

```
$ git archive --format=tar HEAD | gzip > myarchive.tar.gz
```

Question:
After unzipping the archive on the server, how do I connect and sync the server's copy with the remote repository again?

If I do this:

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/myusername:reponame.git
$ git fetch origin
```

git status still reports everything as being untracked.

What *should* I be doing so that my unzipped folder is perfectly in sync with the remote repo, and so I can simply pull any future commits to the remote repo?

Many thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do an archive: do a **[`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle)**: that will give you one file, except you will be able to **pull from it** once copied in the remote location.

See more at "[How can I email someone a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309)"

That bundle can be incremental too (see also "[Difference between git bundle and .patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407577/6309)").
Meaning you don't have to copy over the *full* repos, only the missing commits since the last backup.

I have a scripts which goes to all my bare repos and make a full backup once a week, incremental backups every day (if new commits are detected): [`sbin/save_bundles`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/sbin/save_bundles).

---

As [Nevik Rehnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761499/nevik-rehnel) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948490/how-do-i-connect-a-copy-an-archive-not-a-clone-of-a-git-repository-to-its-rem/24948641?noredirect=1#comment38775650_24948641), git archive would only save one revision, which would make any synchronization in the remote repo incomplete (missing intermediate commits).

Another approach is to [tar the all repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6702057/6309), but that includes too much (including possible private sensitive files, or hook scripts). `git bundle` is the git way.

Comment: it should be mentioned that the reason why `archive` is inappropriate here is that it only packs up the contents of a single revision without any history information -- if it should be re-integrated into a git repo, that information is important, though.

Comment: @NevikRehnel Indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Super! Thanks so much, @VonC and NevikRehnel. I appreciate the explanation and links. Regards, Tim