# How to conduct version control offline(without networking literally)？

Tags: git, svn, github, tortoisesvn, git-svn

Our team is developing the same software project on separate PCs(the networking is blocked due to our company rule), which is really a drug. Now, our developing flow is serial. When member A adds a feature, he had to wait B to finish development and get the copy of the B's project.
So, here is my question:

- how to conduct the version control when the networking is not allowed? Is there some best practices for this? Is there some git implementation that allows us to create a git repository with having to setting up the server and the corresponding key, stuff like that?

Any suggestion will be appreciated?

Comment: Are the two PCs on the same LAN? Why can't you host the git repo on the company's internal private network?

Comment: @anujm no, they are separate PCs, I only can copy things among them by USB flash!  If I host repos in my company's intranet, The procedures to make them available in the isolated Pcs will really complicated, because I have to get many manager's approval! I wonder if it's possible to first crest a git repo in our internal network, then copy the repo to one of the PCs just once. Then, I just conduct the version control among the separate Pcs.

Comment: No homework detected

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) at anytime, and [transmit that single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/6309) the same way you are currently getting a copy of B's project.

That file act as a git repo and does not need any server setup. Once received by the other party, he/she can simply pull from that file, and get the missing commitments.

I had to [develop incremental bundles before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30884514/6309).

Transmitting a repo as a single file limit the risk of data corruption during said transfer.

Comment: Why bundle, not the whole repo for simplicity?

Comment: @LazyBadger The bundle can be the all repo, or just the incremental part of the repo needed by the other party. Again: one file: easier to transfer.

Comment: You can't push to bundle (thus- have to have "bundle per location"), I suggested to have (bare?) repo, which 1) is cloned once 2) doesn't require pure file-copy operation later

Comment: @LazyBadger Sure, that could work too. I just assumed no network means bundle.

Answer (score 0):

> how to conduct the version control when the networking is not allowed?

Easy, even it's SVN

> Is there some best practices for this?

Yes. Keyword "branching and merging"

> Is there some git implementation that allows us to create a git repository with having to setting up the server and the corresponding key

Yes. Default oridnary Git with remote, accessible with `file://` protocol on both workplaces

**Short draft**

If everybody have wait to "...get the copy of..." you **have NOW** method to transfer data from location to location. Thus - just add some things

- every workplace perform job in own branch
- On transferred media normal **repository** is placed, known to local repo as remote target
- On every location pull|push cycle performed and "foreign" work merged in own branch
- When both (all) merges are identical (because they can differ at first step), any "workplace-branch" have to be merged to clean-by-convention mainline-branch

Answer (score 0):

Another option for git would be to use [git format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and `git apply` to exchange changesets in case parallel modifications are required. That is after the initial version of the repository has been copied to the parties.